# TinyMCE Advanced Text editor text color & background color options are not displaying?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I am using `TinyMCE Advanced text editor`. Actually my website was build with  two languages (Arabic , English), the problem is  when i change the language from English to Arabic in the Text Editor `Text color & Text Background color`  options are disappearing , But if it is English version it works fine . can any one help me out of this issue ?

**Arabic Version**
[image]
[image]

**English Version**

Comment: Can you show your code: How are you initialising TinyMCE and how are you changing languages?

Comment: I am using Plugins Language Switcher ,so  by default  the admin control will open in Arabic language ..

Comment: I update the screen shots please look yet .

Comment: Hi Guys i Resolved this issue by installing the 'TinyMCE Color Picker Plugin' . Thanks